# AngularJS + Karma: Unit Testing without loading html as modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

These days I've questioned myself why we need to load the HTML files as modules in the beforeEach section while testing in AngularJS + Karma. I'm using grunt to run karma and I created a task to run the tests using grunt-watch. The very important part is that I load the templates using **$templateCache** instead of loading the template as modules. Is this a terrible idea? Why we need to load HTML as modules?

- How it was before

**The testing file**

```
beforeEach(module("app"));
beforeEach(module('src/modules/networks/views/main-page.html'));
beforeEach(module('src/modules/networks/views/inner-directive1.html'));
beforeEach(module('src/modules/networks/views/inner-directive2.html'));
beforeEach(module('src/modules/networks/views/inner-directive3.html'));
...
```

**The karma conf**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '../',
        files: [
             ...
            'src/app.js',
            'src/routes.js',
            'src/modules/**/*.js',
            'tests/**/*.js',
            'tests/*.js',
            'src/modules/**/*.html'
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            'src/modules/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
        }
    })
};
```

- How it is now

**The testing file**

```
beforeEach(module("app"));
...
```

**The karma conf**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '../',
        files: [
             ...
            'src/app.js',
            'src/routes.js',
            'src/modules/**/*.js',
            'tests/templates.js'
            'tests/**/*.js',
            'tests/*.js',
            'src/modules/**/*.html'
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            'src/modules/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
        }
    })
};
```

I use grunt to generate templates.js every time we change the HTML files.